# Pandas populate new dataframe column based on matching columns in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge, populate

I have a `df` which contains my main data which has one million `rows`. My main data also has 30 `columns`. Now I want to add another column to my `df` called `category`. The `category` is a `column` in `df2` which contains around 700 `rows` and two other `columns` that will match with two `columns` in `df`.

I begin with setting an `index` in `df2` and `df` that will match between the frames, however some of the `index` in `df2` doesn't exist in `df`.

The remaining columns in `df2` are called `AUTHOR_NAME` and `CATEGORY`.

The relevant column in `df` is called `AUTHOR_NAME`.

Some of the `AUTHOR_NAME` in `df` doesn't exist in `df2` and vice versa.

The instruction I want is: when `index` in `df` matches with `index` in `df2` and `title` in `df` matches with `title` in `df2`, add `category` to `df`, else add NaN in `category`.

Example data:

```
df2
           AUTHOR_NAME              CATEGORY
Index       
Pub1        author1                 main
Pub2        author1                 main
Pub3        author1                 main
Pub1        author2                 sub
Pub3        author2                 sub
Pub2        author4                 sub


df
            AUTHOR_NAME     ...n amount of other columns        
Index       
Pub1        author1                 
Pub2        author1     
Pub1        author2 
Pub1        author3
Pub2        author4 

expected_result
            AUTHOR_NAME             CATEGORY   ...n amount of other columns
Index
Pub1        author1                 main
Pub2        author1                 main
Pub1        author2                 sub
Pub1        author3                 NaN
Pub2        author4                 sub
```

If I use `df2.merge(df,left_index=True,right_index=True,how='left', on=['AUTHOR_NAME'])` my `df` becomes three times bigger than it is supposed to be.

So I thought maybe merging was the wrong way to go about this. What I am really trying to do is use `df2` as a lookup table and then return `type` values to `df` depending on if certain conditions are met.

```
def calculate_category(df2, d):
    category_row = df2[(df2["Index"] == d["Index"]) & (df2["AUTHOR_NAME"] == d["AUTHOR_NAME"])]
    return str(category_row['CATEGORY'].iat[0])

df.apply(lambda d: calculate_category(df2, d), axis=1)
```

However, this throws me an error:

```
IndexError: ('index out of bounds', u'occurred at index 7614')
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `on` and `left_index/right_index` work together. Maybe you need `on=['Index', 'AUTHOR_NAME']` (or something similar). And I not sure which dataframe is left in `df2.merge(df,...)`. Maybe you need `how="right"` or `pd.merge(left=df, right=df2, ...)`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Consider the following dataframes `df` and `df2`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        AUTHOR_NAME=list('AAABBCCCCDEEFGG'),
        title=      list('zyxwvutsrqponml')
    ))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        AUTHOR_NAME=list('AABCCEGG'),
        title      =list('zwvtrpml'),
        CATEGORY   =list('11223344')
    ))
```

***option 1***
`merge`

```
df.merge(df2, how='left')
```

***option 2***
`join`

```
cols = ['AUTHOR_NAME', 'title']
df.join(df2.set_index(cols), on=cols)
```

---

***both options yield***

[image]

Comment: Just a quick note .. that worked for me fine .. but in some cases I ended up having duplicates .. still not sure what is the reason for that .. but anyhow, drop the duplicates keeping only one (keep = first OR keep = last) .. check the documentation here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Answer (score 2):

**APPROACH 1:**

You could use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) instead and drop the duplicated values present in both `Index` and `AUTHOR_NAME` columns combined. After that, use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) for checking membership:

```
df_concat = pd.concat([df2, df]).reset_index().drop_duplicates(['Index', 'AUTHOR_NAME'])
df_concat.set_index('Index', inplace=True)
df_concat[df_concat.index.isin(df.index)]
```

[image]

Note: The column `Index` is assumed to be set as the index column for both the `DF's`.

---

**APPROACH 2:**

Use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) after setting the index column correctly as shown:

```
df2.set_index(['Index', 'AUTHOR_NAME'], inplace=True)
df.set_index(['Index', 'AUTHOR_NAME'], inplace=True)

df.join(df2).reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: Well, it works for me though. Did you use the appropriate names for the `DFs` and also Is your `Index` column in both frames set as the index?Please double check. Let me edit the post with the names set by you.

Comment: Yes, the `Index` column in both frames is set as the index and I used the appropriate names for `DFs`

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following. It will merge both the datasets on specified column as key.

```
expected_result = pd.merge(df, df2, on = 'CATEGORY', how = 'left')
```

Comment: As pointed out in comments on previous answers of yours, please provide further context with your answers and format them properly. Otherwise, they will have to be flagged for removal due to low quality. Thank you for helping us keep StackOverflow answers helpful and of high quality!

Answer (score -1):

While the other answers here give very good and elegant solutions to the asked question, I have found a resource that both answers this question in an extremely elegant fashion, as well as giving a beautifully clear and straightforward set of examples on how to accomplish join/ merge of dataframes, effectively teaching LEFT, RIGHT, INNER and OUTER joins.

[Join And Merge Pandas Dataframe](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_join_merge_dataframe/)

I honestly feel any further seekers after this topic will want to also examine his examples...

Comment: But we usually prefer that answers live here, not behind a link to elsewhere.  The only thing I really get from your post is that the solution lies in using `join` and/or `merge`.