# Add a column to pandas dataframe based on value present in different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes like the following (A and B):

```
     ID    color
0     5    red
1     6    blue
2     7    blue
3     8    NaN
4     9    green
5     10   NaN
```

```
     ID    characteristic
0     7    tall
1     9    short
2     24   short
3     1    tall
4     11   medium
5     10   tall
```

for each ID in df A I want to check if there is a corresponding ID in dataframe B . If there is a corresponding ID, then new column in df A should have the value `True`, and if not then `False`

The output should look like this:

```
     ID    color  df_b_presence
0     5    red    False
1     6    blue   False
2     7    blue   True
3     8    NaN    False
4     9    green  True
5     10   NaN    True
```

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question here, it looks like all you need is an `isin` check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), as follows:

```
A['df_b_presence'] = A['ID'].isin(B['ID'])
```

Result:

```
print(A)

    ID  color  df_b_presence
0   5    red          False
1   6   blue          False
2   7   blue           True
3   8    NaN          False
4   9  green           True
5  10    NaN           True
```

Comment: Curious if this satisfies the per-id requirement that I think OP had ... not sure though

Comment: @cs95  My interpretation for per-id is for checking on each row on the `ID` of dataframe `A` for same `ID` in dataframe `B`.   Yup, same not sure though.

Comment: Is this question a duplicate of this one: [Pandas populate new dataframe column based on matching columns in another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39816671/pandas-populate-new-dataframe-column-based-on-matching-columns-in-another-datafr)?

Comment: @Bill  Seems not exactly.  That question is to bring along getting some column values from another dataframe.  This question is on checking existence of same key/value in another dataframe.

Comment: @cs95  Even though there can be duplicated key of `ID` in dataframe A, it just check once more with the same result for each duplicate.  Still same result, I think :-)

Comment: I guess you are right huh!