# Compare and validate a dataset with a given directory dataset in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 datasets, one is a directory which contains the profiles eligible for bonus and other is the actual employee dataset.

I need to compare and validate the employee dataset with directory dataset to ensure which employees are eligible for bonus.

```
# Actual employee dataset

data = {'Name':['Lee', 'Hom', 'Shi', 'Lao', 'Ana'],
        'Designation':['Senior Consultant', 'Analyst', 'Associate', 'Manager', 'Director'],
        'Exp':[7, 4, 1, 10, 16],
        'Skill':['Research', 'Python', 'Excel', 'Finance', 'Leadership'],
        'Qualification':['Msc', 'MTech', 'MCA', 'MBA', 'Phd'],
       'Level':['B1', 'A2', 'A1', 'C1', 'D1']}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
# Dataset of profiles eligible for bonus 

data1 = {'Designation':['Consultant', 'Analyst', 'Associate', 'Manager', 'Director', 'Senior Director', 'VP'],
        'Exp':[7, 4, 2, 10, 16, 20, 25],
        'Skill':['Research', 'Python', 'Excel', 'Finance', 'Leadership', 'Leadership', 'Leadership'],
        'Qualification':['Msc', 'MTech', 'MCA', 'MBA', 'MBA', 'Phd', 'Phd'],
       'Level':['B1', 'A2', 'A1', 'C1', 'D1', 'D2', 'E1']}
 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

The output should be as such that it compares df with df1 and creates a new column and returns value

"Yes" - if everything matches and employee is eligible for bonus
Column Name - if any of the column mismatches

Sample output

```
# Required output
data2 = {'Name':['Lee', 'Hom', 'Shi', 'Lao', 'Ana'],
        'Designation':['Senior Consultant', 'Analyst', 'Associate', 'Manager', 'Director'],
        'Exp':[7, 4, 1, 10, 16],
        'Skill':['Research', 'Python', 'Excel', 'Finance', 'Leadership'],
        'Qualification':['Msc', 'MTech', 'MCA', 'MBA', 'Phd'],
       'Level':['B1', 'A2', 'A1', 'C1', 'D1'],
        'Eligible': ['Designation','Yes', 'Exp', 'Yes', 'Qualification']}
 
    
op = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Comment: This should get you started: [Pandas populate new dataframe column based on matching columns in another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39816671/pandas-populate-new-dataframe-column-based-on-matching-columns-in-another-datafr)

Comment: What about qualification for the last record (PhD vs MBA)?

Comment: Edited, Thanks for highlighting, Corralien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [numpby broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to solve this problem:

```
# Create the dense matrix (cartesian product) between the 2 dataframes
arr = df.iloc[:, 1:].values[:, None] == df1.values

# Find the best match for each Name
idx = arr.sum(axis=2).argmax(axis=1)

# Extract the best match
msk = arr[np.arange(arr.shape[0]), idx]

df['Eligible'] = ((df1.columns * ~msk).to_series(index=df.index)
                      .explode().loc[lambda x: x != '']
                      .groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)
                      .reindex(df.index, fill_value='Yes'))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Name        Designation  Exp       Skill Qualification Level       Eligible
0  Lee  Senior Consultant    7    Research           Msc    B1    Designation
1  Hom            Analyst    4      Python         MTech    A2            Yes
2  Shi          Associate    1       Excel           MCA    A1            Exp
3  Lao            Manager   10     Finance           MBA    C1            Yes
4  Ana           Director   16  Leadership           Phd    D1  Qualification
```